# Move rows from worksheet1 to worksheet2 based on cell value in column AB and paste as values

Tags: vba, excel

I need to selectively copy entire rows from sheet1 to sheet2. I would like to use a "No" value column "AB" to select the applicable rows and then copy the selected rows to sheet2 as values. I was able to create code to copy one row at a time, but would like all rows to copy at once vs. loop and I want the copied rows to be pasted into sheet2 as values.  Can you please help me with this? Here's the code I am using.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Archive()
    Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet
    Set wc = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set wa = Sheets("sheet2")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = wc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row
    Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = lr To 3 Step -1 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
        If wc.Range("AB" & i) = "No" Then
        wa.Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert
        wc.Range("A" & i & ":AG" & i).Cut wa.Range("A3")
        wc.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Archive Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is not what you asked but your `xlDown` should be a `xlUp`.  Right now you are cycling through every row in the sheet.

Comment: Makes sense...Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the elegant solution provided by @Jeeped, the following VBA macro does not use `AutoFilter` feature: instead it utilizes the Excel VBA `Range` `Union` function, enabling to move the entire set of data rows from the Worksheet `wc` to the "archive" Worksheet `wa` at once:

*Listing 1. The solution to move rows using Range Union*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
    Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, I As Long
    Dim uR As Range

    Set wc = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wa = Sheets("Sheet2")
    lr = wc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For I = 3 To lr 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
        If wc.Range("AB" & I) = "No" Then
            If (uR Is Nothing) Then
                Set uR = Range(I & ":" & I)
            Else
                Set uR = Union(uR, Range(I & ":" & I))
            End If
        End If
    Next I
    uR.Copy Destination:=wa.Range("A3")
    uR.EntireRow.Delete

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Archive Completed"
End Sub
```

You may also find useful the extended solution, which displays the number of archived rows using Range `Areas` property as shown below (Listing 2):

*Listing 2. Extended solution to display the number of archived rows*

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
    Dim lr As Long, I As Long, rowsArchived As Long
    Dim unionRange As Range

   'optional unprotect statement if Sheets("Sheet2") is protected
    Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="myPassword"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For I = 3 To lr 'sheets all have headers that are 2 rows
            If .Range("AB" & I) = "No" Then
                If (unionRange Is Nothing) Then
                    Set unionRange = .Range(I & ":" & I)
                Else
                    Set unionRange = Union(unionRange, .Range(I & ":" & I))
                End If
            End If
        Next I
    End With

    rowsArchived = 0
    If (Not (unionRange Is Nothing)) Then
        For I = 1 To unionRange.Areas.Count
            rowsArchived = rowsArchived + unionRange.Areas(I).Rows.Count
        Next I
        unionRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3")
        unionRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

   'optional password-protection  of Sheets("Sheet2")
    Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="myPassword"

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Operation Completed. Rows Archived: " & rowsArchived
End Sub
```

**Note**: both solutions will preserve the formatting of the original rows.

**AS PER YOUR ADDITIONAL QUESTION:** you may use the following VBA statement to unprotect the protected Excel `Worksheet`:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Unprotect Password:="myPassword"
```

and this one to protect it again with the same password:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Protect Password:="myPassword"
```

**AS PER YOUR ANOTHER QUESTION**: refer to the modified code snippet (Listing 2) which demonstrates the Worksheet protect/unprotect functionality implementation details.

Hope this may help.

Comment: HI Alex.  Works great, but wipes out my header rows (rows 1&2) and some of the cell formatting doesn't carry to the sheet2.

Comment: Hi Richard. Please refer to the corrected version (notice uR.Copy Destination:=wa.Range("A3")). What particular formatting is not preserved? Thanks and regards,

Comment: to clarify...both sheets have header rows that are 2 rows and when code is executed it pastes over the sheet2 header rows.

Comment: This issue is already corrected: data rows will be pasted to Worksheet "wa" starting from 3rd row. Anything else?

Comment: You are welcome! I've added the extended solution you may find interesting which returns the number of rows affected. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: One more question please.  Is there an easy way to unprotect sheet2 before running the Macro and then protect it again once the macro has executed?

Comment: Please refer to the extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: Where would the Protect/Unprotect statements go in the code as I'm certainly not an expert with VBA....Thanks!

Comment: OK, please refer to my extended answer per your additional comments/question. At this point I consider the question answered and would appreciate your feedback (i.e. you can mark the answer accepted  if the solution works for you, as per your comments). I would guess, that you possibly are a newcomer and have limited experience with this site (SO), so please be aware that the kind of "Russian Doll Questions" are not quite welcome. Should you have more questions, please post them separately, so I will gladly look into the issue and will  try to help. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) to quickly isolate the rows where column AB is **no**.

```
Sub Archive()
    Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wc = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set wa = Sheets("sheet2")

    With wc
        'if autofilter active, turn it off
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        'cells radiating out from A1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'filter on AB=no
            .AutoFilter field:=28, Criteria1:="no"
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'check if there are rows to copy
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(28))) Then
                    'insert rows at the destination
                    wa.Range("A3").Resize(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(28)), 1).EntireRow.Insert
                    'copy the visible cells
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                    'paste the values an formats
                    With wa.Range("A3")
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                    End With
                    'optionally delete the NO rows
                    .EntireRow.delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        'turn off the autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Archive Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jeeped.  It runs okay if I remove the 'optionally delete the No rows code, but then it doesn't remove the "No" rows from sheet1 and it leaves sheet1 autofiltered and I want it left unfiltered please.

Comment: My apologies. It's just .EntireRow.Delete. and another call to turn off the autofilter. See above.

Comment: Hi Jeeped.  Is there also a way to have the cell formatting in sheet1 replicated in sheet2 as it transfers and some of the formatting is lost?

Comment: That would seem to be a pretty straightforward addition after looking at these [XlPasteType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx). Couldn't you have done that on your own?

Answer (score 0):

just to experiment with solutions with no filtering nor looping through cells

in case "no"s were the only values in column "AB"

```
Sub Archive2()
Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wc = Sheets("sheet01")
Set wa = Sheets("sheet02")

wc.Columns(28).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Copy
wa.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wa.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

MsgBox "Archive Completed"
End Sub
```

otherwise it needs a "helper" column to catch only "No"s in column "AB" (it uses column 29 as the "helper" one: if it interferes with data range, just shift it where appropriate)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
Dim wc As Worksheet, wa As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wc = Sheets("sheet01")
Set wa = Sheets("sheet02")

With wc
    With .Columns(28).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-1] =""No"",1,"""")"
        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
        .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Copy
    End With
    wa.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wa.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Columns(29).ClearContents
End With
wa.Columns(29).ClearContents

MsgBox "Archive Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: edited to add a very short, fast solution should "No"s be the only values in column "AB"